# Is there a way to save and/or auto-apply a filter to the SSMS Object Explorer for a specific connection?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I use a shared hosting service and there are hundreds of databases on the server I share. I just want to see my own databases. I can setup a filter via the interface. But I don't see any way to save/restore the filter without going through the steps each time. What I would really like to do is to connect to the server and then have my filter automatically be in place when I click on "Databases" to open the list. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: No, this is not a feature of SSMS afaik.

Comment: you could perhaps create another user with rights only for those tables you find interesting